# Responsive mobile design html

Tags: html, css, responsive

Creating a web page for the clinic and I can't solve this problem. Images looks different on PC and mobile. I am new to html and css. Tryed to do max-width 100%, but it wont work. Can anyone help me with that, because code is not mine I took over from another person.

[image: WEB]

[image: mobile]

html

```
<!-- STAFF SECTION BEGINS -->
        <section class="staff">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>
                    Spesialister
                </h1>

                <div class="justinas">                        
                    <div class="justinas-picture"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="justinas-background">
                        <h2>
                            Justinas Vitkus
                        </h2>
                        <div>
                            Tannlege 
                        </div>                            
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="jarek">                        
                    <div class="jarek-picture"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="jarek-background">
                        <h2>
                            Jarek Menczak
                        </h2>
                        <div>
                            Tannlege 
                        </div>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .staff .container .justinas .justinas-picture {
  width: 40%;
  height: 60vh;
  background-image: url(../images/naujos_03.2020/22.1.jpg);
  background-size: 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.staff .container .justinas .justinas-background {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.staff .container .justinas .justinas-background h2 {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #0099ff;
  border: solid 4px #0099ff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}
.staff .container .justinas .justinas-background div {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #7d625a;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.staff .container .jarek {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}
.staff .container .jarek .jarek-picture {
  width: 40%;
  height: 60vh;
  background-image: url(../images/staff/jarek.jpg);
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.staff .container .jarek .jarek-background {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.staff .container .jarek .jarek-background h2 {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #0099ff;
  border: solid 4px #0099ff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}
.staff .container .jarek .jarek-background div {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #7d625a;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be part of your question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).